# How to register custom application resources in application.ini in Zend Framework 1.11.x

Tags: zend-framework, resources, application-resource

I have created custom aplication resource:

```
class Custom_Entitymanager extends Zend_Application_Resource_ResourceAbstract{
    //...
    public function init (){
        //...
        $em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($options['connection'],  $config);
        return $em;
    }
}
```

and I put it in `MyProject\library\Custom\Entitymanager.php` file.

When I want to retrieve `Entitymanager` using:

```
$em = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getResource('entityManager');
```

I get null object.

How can I register my custom application resource in `application.ini` file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `application/configs/application.ini`:

```
pluginpaths.Custom_ =  APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Custom"
resources.EntityManager[] =
```

Side note: I'd probably push the EntityManager class down a little deeper into my own custom library, perhaps something like `Custom_Application_Resource_EntityManager`. In this case, the path mapping above would change to:

```
pluginpaths.Custom_Application_Resource_ =  APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Custom/Application/Resource"
resources.EntityManager[] =
```